# Tally database Update with PHP ODBC

Tags: php, odbc

I am facing trouble in updating data in tally database (for a particular company).

I have successfully connect the tally through php-odbc functions and able to fetch data from tally database tables.

But the problem occur while I am trying to modify data in a tally table. I use standard SQL "**UPDATE**" statement for that. But I think I missed something, may be tally ODBC doesn't support "**UPDATE**" statement (As I am try the same in tally calculator window which returns a error that it can't understand the word UPDATE !!).

Tally Version: **Tally.ERP 9 (Educational Mode)**
PHP Version : **PHP 5.3.5**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I was about to ask what you've tried, but it looks like the vendor of this product has elected not to share information about how their ODBC connector works to non-customers.  You're probably going to be up a creek here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For your information, we have a licensed version of tally and their is a third party ERP aplication running which need to be sync with tally.This Tally.ERP Educational version is for testing purpose only.

Comment: Tally ODBC does not expose it in any documentation
i will quote lines from Tally Documentation for Inward connectivity : **"To connect to other programs and use external data in Tally.ERP 9, you can contact the nearest Tally Offices or send an email to support@tallysolutions.com"** [Home > Tally.ERP 9 Series A Reference Manual > Data Management & Administration > Tally ODBC > Inward Connectivity](http://www.tallysolutions.com/website/CHM/TallyERP9/tallyerp9_help.htm#Data_Management/Tally_ODBC.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the database using ODBC, Using ODBC you can only view the database
For that you need to send XML.